# Which is more efficient in using Context in android?

Tags: android, android-context

Which is more efficient between `getApplicationContext()` or this (extends Activity)? Why?

Comment: Change your title. It's not exactly explain your problem.

Comment: Why do you care? I doubt you'll see any difference when profiling and asking this question *before* profiling is [the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference in terms of efficiency as far as I know (and if there is it should be neglectable). The reason why `getApplicationContext()` was introduced is to avoid memory leaks.

For example, if you pass `Activity` as context to some long living object and this object is going to keep this context for it lifetime, you'll have a problem. For example, if configuration is changed or activity is destroyed, the activity is considered dead (as component). But since there is at least one reference to this old `Activity` object it will not be cleaned up by garbage collector.

So, in such cases when you need to store context for longer time you should use `context.getApplicationContext()` instead of directly saving context. And because Application object is always considered "alive" while process is running, there is no memory/resource leaks.

Answer (score -1):

using `getApplicationContext()` is more efficient as i know, because its the major context for the whole application, not instance of context for every activity you are running.

read this : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html , then you will know what am talking about

Comment: Why would a virtual method call (that [calls yet another virtual method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext%28%29)) be cheaper than passing the existing `this` reference as argument?

Comment: read this : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html , then you will know what am talking about